# Get html of select box and append into another div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am creating a selection box using php array and i made that select box hidden.

```
<select id="skuSelect" style="display:none">    
foreach ( $model as $_product):
            $html .='<option value="'.$_product->getId().'" >'. $_product->getName().'</option>';

        endforeach;
</select>
```

now i want to get all html of this hidden select box and want to append it in my custom div

```
var skuSelect = document.getElementById("skuSelect");
var newdiv = '<div>'+skuSelect.cloneNode(true)+'</div>';
```

but when i use jquery append it shows [object HTMLSelectElement] instead of select box

Please help

Answer (score 1):

> The [`Node.cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) method returns a duplicate of the node on which this method was called.(Not the `HTMLContent` of the element)

Create a element using `createElement` and  do `ELEMENT.appendChild(CLONNED_NODE)`

```js
var skuSelect = document.getElementById("skuSelect");
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.appendChild(skuSelect.cloneNode(true));
```

**Using `jQuery`:**

```js
var elem = $('#skuSelect').clone(true);
var wrappedElem = elem.wrap("<div class='new'></div>");
$("#test").append(wrappedElem);
```

Comment: is this possible to take skuSelect.cloneNode(true) in a javascript variable and append it somewhere inside of my custom html. like   var div =skuSelect.cloneNode(true); var newdiv = '<div>hello'+div+'</div>'; jQuery("#test").append(newdiv); ??

Comment: but it still appends  [object HTMLSelectElement] instead of select box